# Different ways to structure a factory in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

Browsing across various AngularJS tutorials online, I noticed that each developer has its own coding preference.

For example, functions in a factory could be written in various ways:

**As a variable**

```
.factory('VariableFactory', function() {

 var someFn = function() {
   // FOO
   return 'foo'
 }

 return {
   someFn: someFn
 }

});
```

**Using This and Self**

```
.factory('SelfFactory', function() {
 var self = this;

 this.someFn = function() {
   // FOO
   return 'foo'
 }

 return self;
});
```

**Or in a return**

```
.factory('ReturnFactory', function() {

 return {
   someFn: function() {
     // FOO
     return 'foo'
   }
 }
});
```

My question are:

- Is there and if so what is the most appropriate way?
- Are there differences in performance?
- What is the link with AngularJS 2.0?

Comment: This could be fairly opinionated question and there will be no difference in performance.. but I would like to know about the link with AngularJS 2.0..

Comment: If you like the second one, you should use service(), not factory(). The third one is less readable than the first one when the service has several, longer functions. It's also easier to have functions call each other when stored in variables. My preference goes to the first one.

Comment: @nizet: why should the second one be a service?